# IF formula for splitting queuing system

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have this table that has been inputted manually:

```
LINE ¦  ROOM A¦ ROOM B¦  ROOM C¦    ROOM D¦ ROOM E¦ ROOM F¦ 
1    ¦    1   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
2    ¦    2   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
3    ¦    3   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
4    ¦    4   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
5    ¦    5   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
6    ¦    6   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
7    ¦    7   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
8    ¦    8   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
9    ¦    5   ¦    4  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
10   ¦    5   ¦    5  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
11   ¦    6   ¦    5  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
12   ¦    6   ¦    6  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
13   ¦    7   ¦    6  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
14   ¦    7   ¦    7  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
15   ¦    8   ¦    7  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
16   ¦    8   ¦    8  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
17   ¦    6   ¦    6  ¦    5   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
18   ¦    6   ¦    6  ¦    6   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
19   ¦    7   ¦    6  ¦    6   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
20   ¦    7   ¦    7  ¦    6   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
21   ¦    7   ¦    7  ¦    7   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
22   ¦    8   ¦    7  ¦    7   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
23   ¦    8   ¦    8  ¦    7   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
24   ¦    8   ¦    8  ¦    8   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
25   ¦    7   ¦    6  ¦    6   ¦    6     ¦    0  ¦    0
26   ¦    7   ¦    7  ¦    6   ¦    6     ¦    0  ¦    0
27   ¦    7   ¦    7  ¦    7   ¦    6     ¦    0  ¦    0
28   ¦    7   ¦    7  ¦    7   ¦    7     ¦    0  ¦    0
29   ¦    8   ¦    7  ¦    7   ¦    7     ¦    0  ¦    0
30   ¦    8   ¦    8  ¦    7   ¦    7     ¦    0  ¦    0
31   ¦    8   ¦    8  ¦    8   ¦    7     ¦    0  ¦    0
32   ¦    8   ¦    8  ¦    8   ¦    8     ¦    0  ¦    0
```

What i'm trying to do is look at the "LINE" column and placing everyone in that column in to "ROOM A" until ROOM A is full (when it hits 8 people). When the 9th person joins the "LINE", the groups are then split into two rooms (ROOM A and ROOM B) and as each person joins the line they get added to each room until each room is full at 8 people again, in this case when the 16th person joins the line the two rooms are full.

If a 17th person joins the line then another room opens and all 17 people are split across the rooms, the people are placed into all 3 rooms until all rooms are full again at 8 people per room. When the 25th person joins the line, all 25 people are then split across 4 rooms etc etc.

So far I have come up with this formula:

```
=IF(IF($A333-8*(COLUMN()-2)>8,12,$A333-8*(COLUMN()-2))<0,0,IF($A333-8* 
(COLUMN()-2)>8,25,$A333-8*(COLUMN()-2)))
```

however I cant quite get it to work, this will read the LINE column and return or rather place a person in to the room until it reaches the number 8, it then moves to the next room and starts placing people there, but i'm not sure if its possible to set a formula that splits the groups like in my example?

is there a formula that can replicate the above where when the first room is full it splits equally the line into two rooms, with the first room having the higher number first if it is odd eg room A has 4 and room B has 3, then if another person joins the line they are placed in Room B to make it equal/even until both rooms are full at 8 again.

Also there is no limit on amount of people joining the queue or how many rooms opens up.

Comment: Your question 'is there a formula that can do this or is this way outside excel's boundaries?' is an open question with too many possible answers, you will have to be more specific. Anyhow, this maybe possible as a formula but will require many if statements and will be very complex. Creating a VBA script to do this may be a better solution. What you have not stated is the maximum number of rooms or people and also how many people would be split across rooms if not a whole number, for example 18 people could be split, 8-8-2 or 8-7-3 or 8-5-5 or 7-6-5 or 7-7-4 or 6-6-6

Comment: will update my question now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I *think* you saying that you want to split *X* people (roughly) evenly between *N* rooms, where *N*=`1+Int((`*`X`*`-1)/8)`?

*For simplicity, I will write all formula as though they go in cell `$B$2`*

Using the above, you can start with your first `IF` statement:

```
=IF(Column()-1<=1+Int(($A2-1)/8), ">=1",0)
```

That's the unused rooms sorted - 0 people each.  Next, let's deal with the whole-numbers:  If you have *X* people in *N* rooms, then there are at least *P* people in each room, where *P*=`Int(`*`X/N`*`)`, with *R* people left over (by definition, *R*=`Mod(`*`X`*`, P)`)

This, then, lets us add a *minimum* to our rooms:

```
=IF(Column()-1<=1+Int(($A2-1)/8), INT($A2/(1+INT(($A2-1)/8))) + "Extra people",0)
```

So, all we need do now, is deal with the *R* extra people.  To make things easy, we'll just add 1 person to each of the first *R* rooms.  This means rooms where `1+`*`R`* is larger than the room number (`Column()-1`).  We can rearrange this to `1+`*`R`*`-(Column()-1)>0`, and again to `2+`*`R`*`-Column()>0`.  *Then* we can take advantage of that >0 by using `Sign` to convert to `1`/`0`/`-1`, and `MAX` to bump the negative numbers up to 0: `MAX(0,2+`*`R`*`-Column())`.  In long-format, this becomes

```
MAX(0,SIGN(2+MOD($A2,INT($A2/(1+INT(($A2-1)/8))))-COLUMN()))
```

Now, shove that in for our "Extra people", and your final formula is as follows:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-1<=1+INT(($A2-1)/8), INT($A2/(1+INT(($A2-1)/8)))+MAX(0,SIGN(2+MOD($A2,INT($A2/(1+INT(($A2-1)/8))))-COLUMN())),0)
```

Comment: this is very useful, thanks for this. I think with my line of formulas and trying to mix in multiple IF's etc i got confused by the middle of it on what to work out.